# Not able to load detectMultiScale method for the grayscale image

Tags: opencv

I am trying to detect face from an image using the haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml features which I downloaded and saved in the same directory where I am running my script.

I get error when I am trying to use the detectMutliScale method.

I printed the image and I see the following after converting it to gray scale

```
[[[158 131 104]
  [157 130 103]
  [157 130 103]
  ...
  [157 123  93]
  [158 124  95]
  [158 124  95]]..
```

I also tried to print after running reading the Haar features from xml file and using the CascadeClassifier

The ouptut of the print is the following:

```
<CascadeClassifier 000001500B2D91B0>
```

I am running this in Microsoft Windows 10 machine with python 3.7.3

```py
import cv2 as cv
original_image = cv.imread('some.jpg')
grayscale_image = cv.cvtColor(original_image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cascade_path = r'\---\Python_Learning\OpenCV\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'
face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier(cascade_path)
detected_faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscale_image)
```

The error I get is the following..

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1658: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Comment: I got the code working using the haarcaccade_frontalface_default..xml by giving explicitly the link where it is downloaded along with the opencv library..Still I am not sure why I am not able to run it when I have these xml files downloaded from the github with the proper path to my local directory?